# actionscript htmlLoader block ads

Tags: html, apache-flex, actionscript

I've got an AIR app that is loading `mx:HTML`s.  I would like to block the ads that show in them  just like Adblock Plus for Firefox does (see http://adblockplus.org/en/).  I subscribe to the Easylist USA filter.

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.google.com");
thisHtmlWindow.open();
thisHtmlWindow.htmlContent.htmlLoader.load(req);
```

I don't know where to begin to interrupt the HTML GET-ting process in actionscript.  This is where I suspect I can add the HTTP filter.  It'd be nice to subscribe to the filter and periodically download it/update it to make sure the major ad networks are blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.  I would start by intercepting the result that comes back from the request, manipulating the HTML, then load it into the HTMLLoader.  You do this by initially retrieving your content using a URLLoader rather than the HTMLLoader.  After you get and manipulate your content, set it into your HTMLLoader using HTMLLoader.loadString.  Hope that helps.

EDIT:  Here's a little code for you.

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

public function loadUrl(url:String):void {
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    _urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onHtmlLoaded);
    _urlLoader.load(request);
}

private function onHtmlLoaded(event:Event):void {
    _urlLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onHtmlLoaded);

    // This is where you can mess with the data before setting it
    var content:String = _urlLoader.data as String;

    myHtmlComponent.htmlLoader.loadString(content);
}
```

Comment: Would you kindly provide the base code for accomplishing this?  I can do this in perl and PHP quite easily, but Actionscript is probably my weakest language.  I'm already set up to compare line by line of the easy list file.